# WSo2 logged in user changes automatically

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have user in wso2 Identity server , say "abcd" (In Primary domain), configured LDAP domain Also. but there is no user with "abcd" as Id.

when I try to login for Wso2 IS management console Initially it will show as Signed-in as:abcd@carbon.super , but after some time it is showing as Signed-in as: LDAP/abcd@carbon.super.

Mostly we saw when we try it from more than one console with same user name. 
why this error?, any known bug or feature?, I'm using wso2 IS 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

Actually we are not aware about such issue.  Thanks for letting people know about this. Did you experience any issues with the functionalities? Or this is just only show in the UI... AFAIK,  this Domain name append to user name, user session contains an some attribute called "DoomainName". I guess, some how this value may have been set in to the session.